# Can someone explain what is this code does?

Tags: c#

Can anyone please explain what does the this code does? Just confused on the this portion of the code (`this.matrix = new  int[rows, cols];`).

```
class Matrix
{   
    private int[,] matrix;

    public Matrix(int rows, int cols)
    {
          this.matrix = new  int[rows, cols];
    }           
}
```

Comment: It is a way of creating a class Matrix which is technically a 2D array in nature.

Comment: Read [Multidimensional Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx) and close this question

Comment: Lack of effort to understand what basic Array or Multi-Dem Arrays do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That code assigns a class variable called `matrix` a new 2d array that has x number of rows and x number of columns..

Of course these aren't mapped to rows and columns as you would see in excel but basically just saying the first array has `rows` length, and the second `column` length such as..

> row1: col col col
>
> row2: col col col

is a `int[2,3]` as is

> col1: row row row
>
> col2: row row row

This is all done in the constructor of an instance of a `Matrix`

You can find more information [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/2d-array)